# sqlyog export query result as csv

Tags: mysql, csv, sqlyog

I'm using SQLyog and I was wonder if would be possible to export query result as csv? What I mean let's say I have query like `SELECT * FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID = 902` and I would get back some rows what I would export as csv.

**Found it! Right click on the result table and use export!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export Query results as CSV with SqLYog is fairly simple: right click on table and export as desired.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make it clear you can see this screenshot.

[image]